# When is it necessary to use more than one Slater determinant to write the wave function of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Consider a system of $N$ non-interacting identical fermions of spin $s$, spin quantum number $m_i=m_{s_i}$and position coordinates $\mathbf{r}_i$. Let $\alpha$ denote a state specified by the numbers $n,j_n$, with $n$ the energy level, $j_n \in \{1,2,...,g_n\}$ and where $g_n$ is the degeneracy of the $n$-th energy level. If each particle is in a spin-orbit state $\psi_{\alpha_i}(\mathbf{r}_i,m_i)$, an antisymmetrized state of the system can be constructed with a Slater determinant as follows:

$$
\Psi_{\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{N}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, m_{1} ; \ldots ; \mathbf{r}_{N}, m_{N}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N !}}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
\psi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, m_{1}\right) & \psi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{2}, m_{2}\right) & \ldots & \psi_{\alpha_{1}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{N}, m_{N}\right) \\
\psi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, m_{1}\right) & \psi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{2}, m_{2}\right) & \ldots & \psi_{\alpha_{2}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{N}, m_{N}\right) \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\psi_{\alpha_{N}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{1}, m_{1}\right) & \psi_{\alpha_{N}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{2}, m_{2}\right) & \ldots & \psi_{\alpha_{N}}\left(\mathbf{r}_{N}, m_{N}\right)
\end{array}\right|
$$

However, is it always sufficient to use a single Slater determinant in order to construct the state of the system? Could it be necessary (or even possible) to use more than one determinants?

Comment: That determinant has made the wavefunction completely antisymmetric under fermion exchanges. What would additional ones accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Only a very restricted class of wavefunctions can be expressed as a single Slater determinant. The Hartree-Fock approximation is only an *approximation* because of this fact.

Writing an $n$-particle  state as single Slater determint is equivalent  to decomposing an element
$$
{\boldsymbol \omega} = \omega_{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n}{\bf e}_{i_1}\wedge {\bf e}_{i_2}\wedge \ldots \wedge {\bf e}_{i_n}
$$
of the exterior algebra as a product
$$
\omega = {\boldsymbol  \eta}_1\wedge {\boldsymbol  \eta}_2\wedge\ldots \wedge {\boldsymbol \eta}_n,
$$
of $n$ vectors. It is easy to see that there  must be restrictions  becuase in an $N$ dimensional Hilbert space there are are more free parameters ($N$-choose-$n$)  in the antisymmetric tensor $\omega_{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n}$ than in the $n$ vectors that only have $nN$ degrees of freedom.

The condition that this can be done  are the [Plucker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding)
$$
\omega_{i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_{n-1},[ j_1}\omega_{j_2,j_3 ,\ldots, j_{n+1}]}=0,
$$
where the $[\ldots]$ denotes antisymmetrization.

A reference  written for physicists is:
*Calculating the distance from an electronic wave function to the manifold of Slater determinants through the geometry of Grassmannians,*
Y.Aoto, M. F. da Silva
Phys. Rev. A 102, 052803 (2020).

Comment: The OP has explicitly restricted the system to contain _non-interacting_ fermions. In this case single Slater determinant is an exact representation of wavefunctions.

Comment: @Ruslan.  No this is not the case. The issue is simple geometry: counting  the dimension of the $n$-particle Hilbert space and the number of parameters in the $n$ factors. Interactions have nothing to do with it. In particular the set of n-by-n Slaters does not form a vector space.

Comment: Oh, I see: we can have entangled states without interactions too. This won't be representable by a single Slater determinant. I was thinking of eigenstates, that's why I thought of interactions as the reason for entanglement.

Comment: @Ruslan: Yes. Exactly   Also there is some deep geometry here as the Plucker relations lie behind the $\tau$ functions in the theory of integrable PDE's due to Sato, Miwa, and Jimbo.